Diagonal and Upper-Triangular pre-conditioning for Jacobi
I am interested in analyzing convergence of the Jacobi method to solve the linear system $Ax=b$,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1   \\
x_2 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1   \\
2 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Of course, we write $A=D-E-F$, with $D=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, E=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -4 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, F= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and the iteration takes the form
$$x^{(k+1)}=Bx^{(k)}+ f, x^{(0)}\in\mathbb{R}^2,$$
with
$$B=D^{-1}(E+F)= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -2 \\-1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, f=D^{-1}b=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 \\2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
We find that the e-values of $B$ are $\pm\sqrt{2}$. Thus, the spectral radius of $B$ is $\sqrt{2}>1$, and the Jacobi method does not converge.
A question I am trying to answers asks whether diagonal or upper-triangular preconditioning will make the method convergent. I know that diagonal will not work, but I am not sure what upper-triangular pre-conditioning is, and I could not find its definition in my textbook. So my question is what is such a preconditioning technique and will it make this iteration convergent? I'm under the impression that preconditioning only changes the rate of convergence of a method and not its actual convergence, but I welcome any correction.

It is indeed unclear what one means by "upper-triangular preconditioning" for Jacobi. Usually, "preconditioning" means that you pick a suitable matrix $P$ and solve the linear system
$$
PAx = Pb
$$
instead of $Ax=b$. However, this trick is typically useful for iterative methods where one does not need to compute $PA$, but only apply it to a vector --- this can be done cheaply by applying $A$ and then $P$, $(PA)v = P(Av)$.
To apply the Jacobi method to $PAx=Pb$, however, you need to access the entries of $PA$, and computing them may cost as much as solving the system with a direct method, so it does not look like a great idea.
Even if the method is not computationally convenient, this still makes a plausible homework question: can you find an upper-triangular $P$ such that the Jacobi method on $PA$ is convergent, for that specific matrix $A$? I won't take the learning experience away from you, if this is indeed homework.
It is also possible to see Jacobi (resp. Gauss--Seidel) as combining the Richardson method with a diagonal (resp. lower triangular) preconditioner. Maybe this is what your question meant? Have those methods been introduced to you in this way? In this case, upper-triangular preconditioning would mean "reverse Gauss--Seidel", i.e. $x^{(k+1)} = (D-E)^{-1}(b+Fx^{(k)})$.
Anyhow, there is little point in trying to figure out what this definition is from an incomplete description. Is this from a university course? Then (1) post the exact text of the exercise (2) double- and triple-check your material; maybe your instructor defined what they mean with preconditioning in this context? (3) ask your instructor. They are the best person to ask, if this is indeed unclear from their handout.

The triangular preconditioning is called Successive Over-Relaxation (SOR) if you allow yourself a damping parameter. You will find theory for this in most books on numerical linear algebra.
